# Regex not allowing number as first character

Tags: regex, angularjs

I'm using following regex not to allow special characters in the text field.

```
/[^\\\/:;\-*?"'<>|()&%@+,$]/g
```

But, this regex is not allowing a number (0-9) as first character.
I'm using angular input box and provided above regex to ng-pattern.

Comment: What do you mean it's not allowing?

Comment: Can you just use /(^[a-z 0-9]*)$/ ?

Comment: It is for me:  [Playground](http://regexr.com/3ai2r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your kind support.

Here is the solution which worked for me:

```
if(/[\\\/:;\-*?"'<>|()&%@+,$]/.test(<Variable to Test>)) { 
     <Show Error>
}
```